Trouble with intallation of OMNET++. After running the mingenv file. I run the make command but I got this error and do not know what it means
clistener.cc
clistener.cc:56:5: warning: 'receiveSignal' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    receiveSignal(c, signalID, checked_int_cast<long>(i,nullptr,msg), d);
    ^
C:/OM++/omnetpp-6.0.3-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0.3/include/omnetpp/clistener.h:206:7: note: 'receiveSignal' has been
      explicitly marked deprecated here
    [[deprecated]] virtual void receiveSignal(cComponent *source, simsignal_t signalID, long i, cObject *details);
      ^
clistener.cc:66:5: warning: 'receiveSignal' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    receiveSignal(c, signalID, checked_int_cast<unsigned long>(i,nullptr,msg), d);
    ^
C:/OM++/omnetpp-6.0.3-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0.3/include/omnetpp/clistener.h:207:7: note: 'receiveSignal' has been
      explicitly marked deprecated here
    [[deprecated]] virtual void receiveSignal(cComponent *source, simsignal_t signalID, unsigned long i, cObjec...
      ^
2 warnings generated.

I run this command
/c/OM++/omnetpp-6.0.3-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0.3$ make

These are warnings, you should be able to execute OMNeT++.
If you want to fix this, replace clang=no at config.user file into main OMNeT++ directory. Thanks
